# blockcypher api generate multisig address

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I want create multisig address on blockcypher api. pubkeys array is required.

$pubkeys = array(
    "02c716d071a76cbf0d29c29cacfec76e0ef8116b37389fb7a3e76d6d32cf59f4d3",
    "033ef4d5165637d99b673bcdbb7ead359cee6afd7aaf78d3da9d2392ee4102c8ea",
    "022b8934cc41e76cb4286b9f3ed57e2d27798395b04dd23711981a77dc216df8ca"
);

But I don't know, how can I create these keys.

Comment: One should never use APIs to generate keys since the API will have information of those keys and thus unsafe. Fi3 has already described a method to generate keys locally using a library.

Comment: Building upon what @Fi3 is saying: You have to generate keys on your client instead of through another service. Otherwise these "private" keys would not be private. Cryp

Answer (score 1):

For generate public keys you can use [bitcore-lib](https://bitcore.io/api/lib/public-key).

For example if you want use HD keys:

```
const HdPrivate = require('bitcore-lib').HDPrivateKey;
const HdPublic = require('bitcore-lib').HDPublicKey;

const root = new HdPrivate();

function newPublic(root, depth){
  //return the public key at depth
  return root.derive(depth).publicKey.toString();
}

const publicKey = newPublic(root, 'm/1');
```

Of course for you must save and keep secret `root`.

Comment: But I can't understand, why we need another library? Must be another way to create these keys?

Comment: I do not know blockcypher api but it seems that it hasn't a method for create key pairs maybe becaouse you should use the [wallet api](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?javascript#wallet-api) instead of create your own wallet logic. Why you can not use another library in your code?

Comment: I need, create and listening address. Is there anyway to make this?

Comment: Do you need multisig address? You have to use just blockcypher?

Comment: Who generate the keys? Is a centrilized service, or is a webapp that generate and manage the key locally or something else?